# USB mounted SSD read/writes slowing down intermitently on Linux server

Tags: linux, usb, ssd

Setup
MoBo  : Super Micro server
Proc  : Twin Xenon with 20 physical cores and 40 threads
RAM   : 128 GB
OS    : Cento 7.x Server
VCard : nVidia Quadro 4000

The task involves writing to and reading from USB mounted SSDs (1TB Micron 5100 Pro formatted vfat) as fast as mechanically possible for data integrity verification.  There are 40 PCIe 2.0 lanes per processor.  One of the 40 has two StarTech USB 3.0 cards with dedicated 5Gbps channels but no extra internal power.  We're using Orico external SSD docs to connect and power the drives.  Outside of different USB docs the server hardware, SSD format, and OS cannot be modified.

And now the actual problem and question.  When we start writing to the drives in a write/read cycle things start out fine.

-Fetch 200Mb to 1.6GB file from remote file server (store in local RAM)
-Write file to each of four USB mounted SSDs (each write is on its own thread)
-Read file from USB mounted SSD for SHA check (also on separate threads)
-Clear file data from RAM
-Repeat until all files are finished

After about a dozen files the write on one or two disks slows down so much that the other disks are forced to wait due to the limits we've placed on number of files held at any given time.  Then the disk will "catch up" and another disk will slow down.  This problem is intermittent and we've written the entire batch of files (up to 1600) with no problems and within 10% of what should be physically possible.

So the questions are what could be causing this and what could we do to prevent this?  Our software ensures that no disk is being written to and read from at the same time nor do we try to read or write more than one file from any given disk at a time.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS This is a different issue from the one I asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1190955/simultaneous-io-to-multiple-ssds-in-external-usb-3-0-enclosures).

EDIT 1: So this may not actually have anything to do with USB, SSDs, drivers, context switching, PCIe bandwidth, etc ....  I just happened to pause execution at a very opportune moment and the std::vector I'm using to store the data to be written was marked as not accessible on the debugger for QtCreator.  A few print statements later and some breakpoints I found that the data is there, the pointer returned by the ::data() function is good, and all is as it should be EXCEPT the local variable in the debugger shows as not accessible.  Yet, every time the vector shows not accessible the write to disk is super long.  So, now I'm on the prowl for something that is corrupting memory or something similar.  Very odd behavior.

Comment: Wow, that's a powerful system! Just a shot in the dark, but what about putting a delay of a few ms between the processing of one file and the next?

Comment: Sadly, we'll be losing it in two weeks to the customer.  :(  My boss has already tried your suggestion with a full second after each read and a full second after each write but the results were the same.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "Write slows down, then catches up, and another SSD slows down" sounds like some internal write buffer is overflowing - everything works as long as the write buffer is accepting data, but the actual write speed is lower than the data coming into the buffer. No idea if this could be a Linux I/O buffer, an USB buffer, or an SSD internal buffer. Have you tested sustained write speeds for a single device? Does that exhibit the same symptoms, or does it work fine?

Comment: Sustained write speeds seem OK but only for one card.  Put the other one on and we've got problems.  But, since we're relying on 3rd party software to get the data and it is a touch flaky even that is questionable.  I was thinking of switching the mount to a asynchronous mount to see if that would help since we're never trying to read and write at the same time.